# Windows Stops Recording Run History (Run MRU list)

Tags: windows-10, run-dialog

When opening *Run* via <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Windows Server 2019, there are no items in its history or Registry key: (I believe the situation is the same in Windows 10)

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
```

- I think it's because I deleted a folder in one of the Windows system directories, and while I can't think of the exact name of that folder, I remember its name contains `history`

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run *Settings > Personalization > Start*, then
enable the option of "Show most used apps":

[image]

If that doesn't fix the problem, use `regedit` to navigate to the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`.
Ensure that the DWORD value named `Start_TrackProgs` is set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it was solved this way:

- Click <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to open `Settings`.
- Navigate to `Privacy` -> `General`.
- Turn on `Let Windows track app launches to improve Start and search results`.